# Windows 10 Update with Windows Server Update Services

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, windows-update, updates

The Windows 10 Clients in my infrastructure don't Update with the local Windows Server Update Services (WSUS) in my network.

I created for the Windows 10 Clients a Group Policy which is configuring the Windows Updates to use the WSUS Server. This is the result, if run rsop.msc with the target windows 10 computer:

```
Configure Automatic Updates
    4 - Auto download and schedule the install
    0 - Every day
    Scheduled install time: 03:00
Specify intranet Microsoft update service location
    Set the intranet update service for detecting updates: http:local-server:8530
    Set the intranet statistics server: http:local-server:8530
Check for updates at the following
    interval (hours): 22
```

The WSUS Server is running on Windows Server 2012 R2 with the update to activate windows 10 updates: **Windows8.1-KB3095113-x64.msu**

Server side it seems like everything is ok and the client just have to install the updates:

[image: wsus client overview]

But if I take a look into the client side event log I see this:

```
0 updates were found
```

[image: Eventlog]

It seems like the client is connecting direct to the microsoft windows network, but is reporting something to wsus server.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the latest client eventlog entry: [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DYD6u.png)

Comment: *You will need to translate everything into English.* I don't understand a single thing in your eventlog.

Comment: I **have** a WSUS Server running in my local network. Look at my screenshots, and sorry for my english.

Comment: I can't understand a single word in your screenshots.  I **can** help you if I can read the information.

Comment: The first shows you the group policy, and the second the overview of the comptuer in wsus. I try to translate it somehow

Comment: I have translated the group policy titles and configuration points, I'm not able to translate the other screenshot, but I think its not nessercary, it just shows you that the wsus thinks the client has to install 117 updates.

Answer (score 2):

Try
`wuauclt /resetauthorization /detectnow`

If that doesn't work, try

```
REG DELETE "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate" /v SusClientId /f

REG DELETE "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate" /v SusClientIdValidation /f
```

Then

`wuauclt /resetauthorization /detectnow`

Comment: I deleted both Registry Keys and run this command, but it doesn't work, no new Updates and no Statistic Update inside the WSUS Console.